# Plotly tick labels misaligned in stacked horizontal bar chart

Tags: reactjs, plotly, plotly.js

I am having trouble getting the yaxis tick labels to align to the bars properly when stacking horizontal bars by using base (my use case is a timeline view so i need empty spaces in between the stacked bars, thus why i am using base)

here is a codepen showcasing the issue: https://codepen.io/dan-wiegand/pen/GRMwKGP?editors=0010

```
var data = [{
  type: 'bar',
  x: [0, 10, 10, 0],
  base: [0, 10, 20, 30],
  y: ['trace 1', 'trace 1', 'trace 1', 'trace 1'],
  orientation: 'h'
}, {
  type: 'bar',
  x: [0, 10, 0, 10],
  base: [0, 10, 20, 30],
  y: ['trace 2', 'trace 2', 'trace 2', 'trace 2'],
  orientation: 'h'
}, {
  type: 'bar',
  x: [10, 0, 10, 0],
  base: [0, 10, 20, 30],
  y: ['trace 3', 'trace 3', 'trace 3', 'trace 3'],
  orientation: 'h'.   
}];
const layout = {
  yaxis: {
    showgrid: true
  }
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
(code required to post codepen link)
```

for those familiar with flex box, it's visually like the difference between space-around and space-between (bars being space between and ticks being space around)

My issue is visible below
[image]and here it is in my actual case - if they all looked like "Copy Valence" that would be perfect
[image]

i dont care if the labels are along the axis lines or in the empty spaces, as long as the labels and the bars are aligned! In a perfect world the chart would be aligned like below, with the tick labels in the space between the ticks and the bars between ticks
[image]

Comment: javascript or python? both sets of tags are on question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- question is tagged with **python** and **javascript**.  Solution on **python** but concept same across languages
- for each trace use a separate yaxis *y, y2, y3*
- in layout set domain of each yaxis

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = [
    {
        "type": "bar",
        "x": [0, 10, 10, 0],
        "base": [0, 10, 20, 30],
        "y": ["trace 1", "trace 1", "trace 1", "trace 1"],
        "orientation": "h",
        "yaxis": "y",
    },
    {
        "type": "bar",
        "x": [0, 10, 0, 10],
        "base": [0, 10, 20, 30],
        "y": ["trace 2", "trace 2", "trace 2", "trace 2"],
        "orientation": "h",
        "yaxis": "y2",
    },
    {
        "type": "bar",
        "x": [10, 0, 10, 0],
        "base": [0, 10, 20, 30],
        "y": ["trace 3", "trace 3", "trace 3", "trace 3"],
        "orientation": "h",
        "yaxis": "y3",
    },
]

go.Figure(data).update_layout(
    {
        ax: {"showgrid": True, "domain": [i * 0.33, (i + 1) * 0.33]}
        for i, ax in enumerate(["yaxis", "yaxis2", "yaxis3"])
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! i added both python and js tags just to reach more people since it's an easy translation from one to the other!